# PHP: $row undefined variable

Tags: php, html, mysql, database, row

My problem is I want to show the details of a user profile that I have on my database. For some reason, it keeps giving me errors of 'Undefined variable: row'.

[image: This is an image of the problem]

Also, I can show the user Username and UserID using this code. (HTML CODE)

So I'm not really sure what's missing or if I did something wrong.

Hope that you could help me.

THANK YOU in advance :)

PHP CODE - DB CONNECTION & SQL QUERY

```
<?php
$id = session_id();
if ($id == "") {
    session_start();
}
if (!isset($_SESSION['username'])) {
    header("Location: login.php");
} //redirects to the login page if the user is not logged in

if($_POST){       
    try {
        $host = '127.0.0.1';
        $dbname = 'webdev_2014376';
        $user = 'root';
        $pass = '';
        # MySQL with PDO_MYSQL
        $DBH = new PDO("mysql:host=$host;dbname=$dbname", $user, $pass);
    } catch(PDOException $e) {echo 'Error';}   

    ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

    $sqlQuery = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE UserID = :UserID LIMIT 1";            
    $statement = $DBH->prepare($sqlQuery);    
    $status = $statement->execute();

    if (!$status) {
        die("Could not retrieve user");
    }$row = $sqlQuery->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

    if(isset($row)){
        $_SESSION['id'] = $row['UserID'];  
        $_SESSION['username'] = $row['Username'];
        $_SESSION['firstname'] = $row['FirstName']; 
        $_SESSION['lastname'] = $row['LastName'];        
        $_SESSION['email'] = $row['Email'];        
        $_SESSION['birthday'] = $row['Birthday'];       
        $_SESSION['phonenumber'] = $row['PhoneNumber'];
    }      
}   

?>
```

HTML CODE

```
    <body>
        <div class="container container_12">
            <div class="header grid_12">
                <div class="headerTitle grid_6 alpha">
                    <h1>Facebook Again!</h1>
                </div>

                <?php
                if (isset($_SESSION['username'])) {
                    echo '<div class="headerNav grid_6 omega">';
                    echo '<ul>';
                    echo '<li class="grid_1 alpha"><a href="index.php">Home</a></li>';
                    echo '<li class="grid_2 push_1"><a href="profile.php?UserID='.($_SESSION['id']).'">'. ($_SESSION['username']) . '</a></li>';
                    //echo '<li class="grid_2 push_1"><a href="profile.php?UserID=11">' . ($_SESSION['Username']) . '</a></li>';
                    echo '<li class="grid_2 omega push_1"><a href="logout.php"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-log-in"></span> Logout</a></li>';
                    echo '</ul>';
                    echo '</div>';
                }
                else {
                    echo '<div class="headerNav grid_6 omega">';
                    echo '<ul>';
                    echo '<li class="grid_2 alpha"><a href="login.php">Login</a></li>';
                    echo '<li class="grid_2 omega"><a href="register.php">Register</a></li>';
                    echo '</ul>';
                    echo '</div>';
                }
                ?>

            </div>
            <div class="profile grid_12">
                <div class="profPic  grid_3 suffix_1 alpha">
                    <img src="images/profile/RTZ.jpg" style="width: 300px; height: 300px;">               
                </div>
                <div class="profText prefix_1 grid_7 omega">
                    <?php

                        echo "<h1>Profile of " . $_SESSION['username'] . "</h1>";

                            echo '<tr>';
                            echo '<td class="vedHeaders">First Name: </td>' . '<td class="vedOutput">' . $_SESSION['firstname'] . '</td><br/>';
                            echo '</tr>';
                            echo '<tr>';
                            echo '<td class="vedHeaders">Last Name: </td>' . '<td class="vedOutput">' . $row['LastName'] . '</td><br/>';
                            echo '</tr>';
                            echo '<tr>';
                            echo '<td class="vedHeaders">Email: </td>' . '<td class="vedOutput">' . $row['Email'] . '</td><br/>';
                            echo '</tr>';
                            echo '<tr>';
                            echo '<td class="vedHeaders">Birthday: </td>' . '<td class="vedOutput">' . $row['Birthday'] . '</td><br/>';
                            echo '</tr>';
                            echo '<tr>';
                            echo '<td class="vedHeaders">Phone Number: </td>' . '<td class="vedOutput">' . $row['PhoneNumber'] . '</td><br/>';
                            echo '</tr>';
                    ?>
                </div>
            </div>

    </body>
```

Comment: question is now, was the session started in all pages using sessions? your second piece of code doesn't imply that it was.

Comment: hi, all the code are together in one page. and all of the different pages i have the started the sessions :)

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.error-handling.php --- http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php are good tools to check for errors. Also view your HTML source and use `var_dump()`.

Comment: One thing that is important to note is; while assigning a row's column to a fetch is lettercase. `UserID` is not the same as `userid` etc. should your column names be in lowercase.

Comment: *"hi i just tried your suggestion there $statement->bindParam(':UserID', $UserID); and it's still not working – Marky B 2 mins ago"* - There is nothing in your question to support where `$UserID` is assigned (error reporting would have thrown you something about it, being unassigned). Please update your question as an ***additional edit*** http://stackoverflow.com/posts/34557030/edit under your original question and NOT overwriting your original post, but as a *"Here is my (new) current code..."*.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the HTML code you're using `$row['LastName']` when it should be `$_SESSION['lastname']` (and the same for the other variables). `$row` is only set when you're processing `POST` data and you do the SQL query, it's not set when the page is opened without submitting a form.

Comment: btw thank you for editing the question, i'm new here. but I already tried what you have suggested and it isn't working for me. :/

Comment: The session variable is named `lastname`, not `LastName`. You need to use the same session variables when you're displaying as when you assigned it.

Comment: You're also missing a call to `$statement->bindParam()` before `$statement->execute()`, so there's no value for `:UserID`. Is that a copying error or a mistake in the real script?

Comment: @Barmar ^ true (good catch). However, it's unsure whether they started the session in their 2nd body of code (HTML). I've placed a comment under their question about it, but gotten no response.

Comment: @Fred-ii- I think the second body is part of the same script.

Comment: @Barmar hi i just tried your suggestion there `$statement->bindParam(':UserID', $UserID);`  and it's still not working

Comment: You never set `$UserID`.

Answer (score 1):

I think the Problem is that you look for `isset($row)`. Cause the row will allways set on post BUT if there is a entrie in database you will get a row ELSE you will get false.

and then you try to access to "false" like an array.

Answer (score 0):

Use $_SESSION instead of $row, and be careful with indexes, as in $_SESSION array you have lowercase : $_SESSION['lastname'] $_SESSION['email'] and so on, - array keys are case sensitive.

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem here is you need to start the session before you check that a session id is set, try starting the session then validating the session variables after:

```
session_start();

if (!isset($_SESSION['username'])) {
    header("Location: login.php");
}
```

Comment: Also I can't see where you bind the :UserID parameter in your query. http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.bindparam.php

Answer (score -2):

use  `$_SESSION` instead of `$row`.

Comment: I wish I'd said that 10 minutes earlier. Yeah, I did.

Comment: *"use $_SESSION instead of $row"* - where exactly? Giving an explanation will benefit everyone, including "which" one(s).