# PHP there's only 1 row is returned then duplicates it

Tags: php, mysql, row

I was wondering if anyone can explain to me why its only returning 1 row when there are 5 different rows in mysql table.

It's only showing the 1st row in all 5 rows, because I placed it in a while loop (HTMLcode) so that it can print all the other rows not just the first one.

[Image that shows the problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/74gLc.jpg)


THANK YOU IN ADVANCE :)


PHP CODE

```
$id = session_id();
if ($id == "") {
    session_start();
}
if (!isset($_SESSION['username'])) {
    header("Location: login.php");
}

// making the connection to the database
try {
    $host = '127.0.0.1';
    $dbname = 'webdev_2014376';
    $user = 'root';
    $pass = '';
    # MySQL with PDO_MYSQL
    $DBH = new PDO("mysql:host=$host;dbname=$dbname", $user, $pass);
} catch(PDOException $e) {echo 'Error';}  

//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

// selecting the row from the database
$sqlQuery = $DBH->prepare("SELECT * FROM users");   

// running the SQL
$sqlQuery->execute();
// pulling the data into a variable
$row = $sqlQuery->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

// taking each individual piece
$UserID = $row['UserID'];
$username = $row['Username'];
$firstname = $row['FirstName'];
$lastname = $row['LastName'];

?>
```

HTML CODE

```
<?php
     echo 'hello, ' . $_SESSION['username'];
     echo '            ';
     echo $_SESSION['id'];
?>

            <div>   
               <table class="table table-bordered table-hover">
                    <thead>
                        <tr>
                            <th class="TableCol1"> Username </th>
                            <th class="TableCol2"> First Name </th>
                            <th class="TableCol3"> Last Name </th>
                            <th class="TableColOpt"> Options </th>
                        </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody>
                        <?php
                        while ($check)  {
                            echo '<tr>';
                            echo '<td class="prEach1">' . $username . '</td> ';
                            echo '<td class="prEach1">' . $firstname . '</td> ';
                            echo '<td class="prEach3">' . $lastname . '</td> ';
                            echo '<td class="prEach4 optlinks"> '
                            . '<a href="profile.php?UserID='.$UserID.'">View</a> '
                            . '</td>';
                            echo '</tr>';

                            $check = $sqlQuery->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
                        }
                        ?>
                    </tbody>
                </table> 
            </div>
```

**-------------------------------------------------------

EDIT




I FOUND THE SOLUTION**

[SOLUTION IMAGE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7Q2DF.jpg)

PHP CODE

```
<?php
$id = session_id();
if ($id == "") {
    session_start();
}
if (!isset($_SESSION['username'])) {
    header("Location: login.php");
}

// making the connection to the database
try {
    $host = '127.0.0.1';
    $dbname = 'webdev_2014376';
    $user = 'root';
    $pass = '';
    # MySQL with PDO_MYSQL
    $DBH = new PDO("mysql:host=$host;dbname=$dbname", $user, $pass);
} catch(PDOException $e) {echo 'Error';}  

//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

// selecting the row from the database
$sqlQuery = $DBH->prepare("SELECT * FROM users");

// running the SQL
$sqlQuery->execute();
// pulling the data into a variable
$check = $sqlQuery->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);



?>
```

HTML CODE

```
<?php
echo 'hello, ' . $_SESSION['username'];
echo '            ';
echo $_SESSION['id'];
?>

<div>   
   <table class="table table-bordered table-hover">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th class="TableCol1"> Username </th>
                <th class="TableCol2"> First Name </th>
                <th class="TableCol3"> Last Name </th>
                <th class="TableColOpt"> Options </th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <!-- This is the category fields on the list. -->
        <tbody>
            <?php
            //$check = $sqlQuery->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
            while ($check)  {

                echo '<tr>';
                echo '<td class="prEach1">' . $check['Username'] . '</td> ';
                echo '<td class="prEach1">' . $check['FirstName'] . '</td> ';
                echo '<td class="prEach3">' . $check['LastName'] . '</td> ';
                echo '<td class="prEach4 optlinks"> '
                . '<a href="profile.php?UserID='.$check['UserID'].'">View</a> '
                . '</td>';
                echo '</tr>';

                $check = $sqlQuery->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC); //THIS SHOULD BE AT THE BOTTOM JUST BEFORE THE WHILE LOOP ENDS
            }
            ?>
        </tbody>
        <!-- This is the get methods of the properties, where the output of the user put in the Property form will be shown -->
    </table> 
</div>
```

Comment: This looks like a next-to exact duplicate of your other question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34557030/php-row-undefined-variable where answers were given but wasn't marked as solved. So, what's so different with this one? Edit: You're making the same mistake.

Comment: Google "php pdo fetch" yields http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.fetch.php, which says "Fetches the next row from a result set". Have a look at fetchAll; try to understand what's happening.

Comment: @Fred-ii- Hi, yeah, I figured that other question out, and now im trying to figure out hoe to show ALL rows and not just one, but this one is only showing the first row when there are rows.

Comment: so why isn't there a green tick next to Barmar's answer, where you didn't respond to his last comment? Edit: ok, you marked it now.

Comment: @Fred-ii- im sorry im new here, i didnt know u were supposed to that, ill do that in the future. Thanks

Comment: so, did you start the session in all pages? Your 2nd body of code doesn't show `session_start();` so that's unknown. Plus, you're not "obligated" per se, it's just better to do so. In accepting an answer, it informs everyone that a solution was found. If not, then it remains in the unanswered category. That's the main reason why it's important and everyone gets points in return; this means "you" also ;-)

Comment: now to answer this, your `$check = $sqlQuery->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);` is below `while ($check)` and that is why it's failing, and possibly the missing `session_start();`. and this `?UserID`  requires a `$_GET['UserID']` somewhere which isn't present in your posted code and I don't know where you are getting it from.

Comment: @Fred-ii- yes, all the pages have `session_start();` the code that i posted here, is located in one php page. soz forgot to state it again ><

Comment: `$check = $sqlQuery->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC); while ($check)  {...}` and not the other way around. Error reporting would have helped you here. You'd of gotten an `undefined check variable` notice had you had it set.

Comment: @Fred-ii- if i put it like this outside the while loop `$check = $sqlQuery->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC); while ($check) {...}` it continuously loops like forever lol

Comment: There surely must be an end *somewhere*. How many rows do you have?

Comment: @Fred-ii- I have 5 rows in my mysql table, i tried putting the $_GET['UserID'], it doesnt really need it in this page, because in the URL it doesnt have a `?UserID=` its only called index.php xD

Comment: @Fred-ii- I found a solution I just edited the post ^, but not its showing the other rows, and not the first ROW ><

Comment: @MarkyB Please see the **Solution** section of my answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I was wondering if anyone can explain to me why its only returning 1 row when there are 5 different rows in mysql table.

Look what's happening inside `while` loop,

```
while ($check)  {
    echo '<tr>';
    echo '<td class="prEach1">' . $username . '</td> ';
    echo '<td class="prEach1">' . $firstname . '</td> ';
    echo '<td class="prEach3">' . $lastname . '</td> ';
    echo '<td class="prEach4 optlinks"> '
    . '<a href="profile.php?UserID='.$UserID.'">View</a> '
    . '</td>';
    echo '</tr>';

    $check = $sqlQuery->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
}
```

Initially you fetched only one row from the result set using `$row = $sqlQuery->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);` and put the values in the respective variables. In the `while` loop you're looping through the result set but actually `echo`ing same old variables.

**Solution:**

If you want to display all the result set rows(including the first row) inside your table cells, then first delete these four lines,

```
$row = $sqlQuery->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

$UserID = $row['UserID'];
$username = $row['Username'];
$firstname = $row['FirstName'];
$lastname = $row['LastName'];
```

And then loop through the result set like this,

```
// your code

<?php
    while ($row = $sqlQuery->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){
        echo '<tr>';
        echo '<td class="prEach1">' . $row['Username'] . '</td> ';
        echo '<td class="prEach1">' . $row['FirstName'] . '</td> ';
        echo '<td class="prEach3">' . $row['LastName'] . '</td> ';
        echo '<td class="prEach4 optlinks"> '
        . '<a href="profile.php?UserID='.$row['UserID'].'">View</a> '
        . '</td>';
        echo '</tr>';

    }
?>

// your code
```

Comment: Hey, I just found a solution as well, I just edited my post there, THANK YOU THO :) our answers are kinda similar but instead of you putting this as the statement `$row = $sqlQuery->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)` i placed mine inside the while loop, just before the while loop ends :)

Comment: @MarkyB I was writing the answer, hence didn't see your edit. Glad the issue is resolved. Cheers! :)